# Flutter - Error del reproductor con el paquete Chewie

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo diferentes pantallas que reproducen diferentes videos, como aplicación de aprendizaje, avanza entre esas pantallas, en los respectivos initState y dispose tienen el mismo código para cargar y cerrar los controladores de video_player y chewie, en ciertas pantallas al avanzar, da el error de la imagen. Pero no es siempre la misma pantalla, porque pueden salir en cierta pantalla, para volver después y continuar en la última pantalla que vio. Les dejo las capturas del error, código y flutter doctor. Espero que puedan ayudarme.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: aquí hay algo relacionado, podrías revisar el hilo https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/81804

Comment: El código va _como texto, con formato_. Lee [ask].